# How to start mongdb in Linux mint?

Tags: mongodb, linux-mint

I would like to ask on how to start mongodb in linux mint. I tried `sudo service mongod start` but it shows the error `mongod: unrecognized service`. Why is this happen. When I run the sudo service in ubuntu Linux there is no problem like this. BUt why its not work in Linux mint? Is there a solution for this?

Comment: how did you install mongodb?

Comment: I just followed the tutorial from here http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

Comment: I think you need to use service mongo start, without the d in there.

Comment: can you try running 'which mongod' ?

Answer (score 2):

I just installed Mongo DB in LinuxMint Sarah (18) and for me, the following command worked:

sudo service mongodb start.

Checking that it works can be done either by executing 'top' command or checking the log file in mongodb folder (instructions in the following link ---> https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#run-mongodb-community-edition)

For stopping mongodb, the same command but typing stop 'sudo service mongodb stop'

In the previous link, both commands are included but without the 'b', maybe they just made a typing mistake :)